# Haskell understanding some functions

Tags: haskell, stream

Can someone please explain why the first function generates the stream `"a"`, `"aa"`, `"aaa"` .. ? 
Or why the second generates a stream of prefixes for example: 
`prefixes [1,2,3..]` -> `[[],[1],[1,2], [1,2,3]..]`

```
strings = "" : ( map ('a' :) strings )
prefixes (x : xs) = [] : ( map (x :) (prefixes xs) )
```

Comment: Write these functions down on paper and see what they expand to when you insert concrete arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're both pretty similar, so I'll just show you `strings` and let you figure out `prefixes` on your own as an exercise.

Haskell likes being both recursive and lazy.  Laziness means that values are represented by *thunks*, or promises of future computations.  You can actually see them in GHCi when you evaluate something:

```
> let strings = "" : map ('a' :) strings
> :print strings
strings = (_t1 :: [[Char]])
> strings !! 0
""
> :print strings
strings = "" : (_t2 :: [[Char]])
> strings !! 1
"a"
> :print strings
strings = "" : "a" :: (_t3 :: [[Char]])
> strings !! 2
"aa"
:print strings
strings = "" : "a" : "aa" : (_t4 :: [[Char]])
```

Each `_tN` represents a pointer to the rest of the stream that hasn't been evaluated yet.  You can also visualize it like this, where the `_` represents the pointer to the rest of `strings`

```
strings
    = "" : map ('a':) strings
      ^--------<------^
    = "" : map ('a':) ("" : _)
           ^--------<-------^
    = "" : ('a':"") : map ('a':) (_)
           ^--------<-------------^
    = "" : "a" : map ('a':) ("a" : _)
                 ^-------<---------^
    = "" : "a" : ('a':"a") : map ('a':) (_)
                 ^---------<-------------^
    = "" : "a" : "aa" : map ('a':) ("aa" : _)
                        ^--------<---------^
    = "" : "a" : "aa" : ('a':"aa") : map ('a':) (_)
                        ^----------<-------------^
    = "" : "a" : "aa" : "aaa" : map ('a':) ("aaa" : _)
                                ^---------<---------^
    = "" : "a" : "aa" : "aaa" : ('a':"aaa") : map ('a':) (_)
                                ^------------<------------^
    = "" : "a" : "aa" : "aaa" : "aaaa" : map ('a':) ("aaaa" : _)
                                         ^---------<----------^
    = ...
```

Hopefully this makes sense, each `^-<-^` shows what the `_` is pointing at in each iteration (roughly)

Answer (score 7):

These are both some really interesting "tying the knot" examples. You can understand them operationally by carefully following the evaluation, being sure to not evaluate too much ever. You can also understand them equationally. Sometimes the latter is easier

For instance, if we consider a slight variation on `strings`

```
strungs = map ('a':) strungs
```

we can think of the answer as being whatever value `strungs` goes unchanged if you `map ('a':)` over it. If we imagine `strungs` is a list of strings (and it must be by the types) then performing `map ('a':)` to that list adds a new 'a' to the front of each element.

Thus the only choice of `strungs` that goes unchanged after such a map is if it's a list of any length where each element is the infinite string "aaaaa...".

Now `strings` is a lot like `strungs`, but it has another condition. Whatever `strings` is, it has to be the same as `"" : map ('a':) strings`. It's easy to see that we're playing a similar kind of game here as we did with `strungs`, except that we keep adding new empty elements. Thus, `strings` must look like

```
"", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", ...
```

because `map ('a':) strings` looks like

```
"a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa", ...
```

and then prepending `""` makes it the same as what we started with

```
"", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa", ...
```